# Find solution for differential equations $\frac{dx}{dt} = |x|$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find solution for differential equations $\frac{dx}{dt} = |x|$.

My idea:
I try prepare three cases:

1. when $|x(t)| > 0$ then $x(t) = C_{2}e^{t}$
2. when $|x(t)| < 0$ then $x(t) = C_{3}e^{-t}$
3. for $|x(t)|=0$ then $x(t)=0 $

We have: 
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x$$
$$\frac{dx}{x} =  dt$$
$$\int \frac{dx}{x} = \int dt$$
$$ \ln(x)= t + C_{0}$$
$$ x = C_{1}e^{t}$$

And 2.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = -x $$
$$\frac{dx}{-x} = dt$$
$$\ln(x) = -t - C_{2} $$
$$x = C_{3}e^{-t}$$
For 3. I think physically, I assume that velocity $\frac{dx}{dt}$ is 0 then movement x(t) is zero.

I need review my work and observations. Many thanks!

Comment: Could you please improve the language in point 3.? What did you intend to express with *"movement $x(t)$ is zero"*?

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are right but I don't like your third argument because if $\frac {dx}{dt}$ is velocity, then $x $ is position, not "movement". Thus with this physical argument, $x $ should be a constant, not necessarily zero.

The reason for being zero is actually that if any real number $|x| = 0$ then $x=0$, it doesn't really matter the derivative on the LHS in this case.

Comment: *"Velocity zero"* literally translates into *"no movement"*. That this additionally means *"not moving away from the initial value $x=0$"* is implied. However, the language in question is poor, it should be at least *"the movement of $x(t)$ is zero"*.

Comment: I know, I never said that "no movement" was wrong. I was just pointing out that in this context, $x$ means "position", not "movement". The initial value $x=0$ is an arbitrary choice of yours, you may have chosen any other number instead of $0$ and keep that constant.

Comment: Yes, the solution of $f(x)=0$ for a general autonomous ODE $\dot x=f(x)$ can be anywhere, in the present case it is at $x=0$. Whatever, if OP does not correct the language in the question, we will not be certain about the intended meaning.

Comment: In my opinion the question is clear, and the fact that the solution in the third case is $x=0$ follows from the premise $|x|=0$, and has nothing to do with the fact that this is an ODE. The OP just mixed "position" and "movement" thus holding a wrong argument, but still getting the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

From general principles, the ODE is autonomous and the right side is globally Lipschitz continuous in $x$ (with constant $1$), so that the existence-and-uniqueness theorem (Picard-Lindelöf, Peano-Lipschitz, Cauchy-whatever...) applies. Solutions are globally defined and unique.

Thus the value of $x$ where the right side is zero, $x=0$, gives a constant solution that separates the solution family. Therefore none of the other solution changes sign, they are either positive everywhere or negative everywhere.

Then your arguments apply (but without the absolute values in the case descriptions, $|x(t)|<0$ makes no sense).